# iOS : Integrate Firebase InAppMessaging with Cordova project

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, firebase-in-app-messaging

I need to add Firebase InAppMessaging with iOS Cordova project. I have been following Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started) from official website

How can I use this to add into Cordova based project? I have created pod files as describe in documentation, However application is still now loading in-App Messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) project, that have Inapp Messaging and others firebase features already for cordova.